What is the default hue in angular material 3?
What is the default hue for angular material 3?
I can't seem to find that information.
Also, if I have a material button for which I want to use some hue other than default, is there a way to write something like ... color="primary-200" out of the box?

Using the button examples page it looks like --mdc-filled-button-container-color is 80 and --mdc-fab-container-color is 30 for the available themes anyway. I took the hex codes and compared them to the available palettes.

I don't know of a good way to do what you're asking without a mixin for your button. Maybe check out customizing using design tokens? Not sure enough about either of these to make a proper answer.

@DM when you say a mixin for button you mean extract color for the button into mixin and then get color variable from theme through material api? (as shown in docs)

Yes, basically. Use a mixin to get the values for the hue you want and assign them to a class that you add to the button (or use the mat.button-colors($theme) approach if you want it site-wide).

I'm thinking specifically about the example at the bottom of the page that uses mat.get-theme-color($theme, primary, 20);.
